# Writing code for a diagram

Tags: plotting, drawing

Could anyone please help in writing the code for the following diagram in Mathematica?

[image]

Note: I want a simple code in Mathematica without using an external package.

Comment: Ok, you didn't like a perfectly reasonable answer by Nasser, but are not willing to show what have you tried yourself. Can you explain why can't you just use [`Arrow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html) and [`Line`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) inside [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use MaTeX?

```
MaTeX["\\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b] {i1--[anti fermion] 
a--[anti fermion] i2,a--[photon] b};", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this needs lualatex and not pdflatex, which is the default used by `MaTeX`. I do not know how to tell `MaTeX` to use lualatex instead of pdflatex as the default compiler, so I cheated a little. You need to do the following before issuing the above command.

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]

ConfigureMaTeX["pdfLaTeX" ->"C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\lualatex.exe"];

SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{tikz}\\usepackage{tikz-feynman}"}]
```

And now you can issue the command.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is also `FeynCalc` which is *is a Mathematica package for symbolic evaluation of Feynman diagrams* but I never used it myself and do not have it installed. You could look at it.

There is also old `FeynArts` https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/1638/  *this paper describes the Mathematica package FeynArts used for the generation and visualization of Feynman diagrams*

**Update**

> Note: I want a simple code in Mathematica without using an external
> package.

The above was added later. Here is a quick plot using standard Mathematica Graphics. Feel free to adjust as needed

```
Graphics[{First@Plot[1/2 Sin[3*x], {x, 0, 3*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black],
  {Arrowheads[{0, 0, 0.05, 0}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-2, 2}}]},
  {Arrowheads[{0, 0, 0.05, 0}], Arrow[{{-2, -2}, {0, 0}}]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Also could you please label say a, b, c all of the three lines

One option is to use `Text`and adjust the location as needed.

```
Graphics[{First@
   Plot[1/2 Sin[3*x], {x, 0, 3*Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> Black], {Arrowheads[{0, 0, 0.05, 0}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-2, 2}}]}, {Arrowheads[{0, 0, 0.05, 0}], 
   Arrow[{{-2, -2}, {0, 0}}]},
  Text[Style["a", Red, 16], {-1.5, -1.8}],
  Text[Style["b", Red, 16], {-1.5, 1.9}],
  Text[Style["c", Red, 16], {3, .8}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: that's fine, but I want a simple code in Mathematica without using an external package.

Comment: 2nd, Why one not use tikz-Feynman directly in Latex rather than using in Mathematica!

Comment: _Why one not use tikz-Feynman directly in Latex rather than using in Mathematica!_ Well, you said  yourself you wanted the diagram in Mathematica _diagram in Mathematica_  I assumed as part of your other notebook diagrams.  If you do not need it in Mathematica, then why not just Latex directly?  You are asking this in Mathematica forum.  MaTeX is very useful package that allows one to use Latex functionality from inside Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and great help! I wanted the second and I think the direct Mathematica code is much easier to modify.

Comment: Also could you please label say a, b, c all of the three lines

Comment: @SciJewel you can use Text and play around with the location as shown.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 10):

The arrows can be drawn using "Arrow" and for the wiggly line we use a Bezier curve.

For the Bezier curve some control points are needed. We choose control points at a distance of +/-0.5 above/below the y and 0.5 spaced along the x axis:

```
dx = 0.3;
dy = 0.5;
n = 7;
ctrl = Table[{i dx, Mod[i, 3, -1] dy}, {i, n}]
```

With this we can now draw the diagram:

```
gr=Graphics[{Thickness[0.01]
  , Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{{-1, -1}, {0, 0}}, 0.5], 
  Line[{{-1, -1}, {0, 0}}]
  , Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-1, 1}}, 0.5], Line[{{-1, 1}, {0, 0}}]
  , BezierCurve[Join[{{0, 0}}, ctrl, {{++n dx, 0}}]]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please draw another diagram in addition to the above with a dot/blob instead of the wavy line? Second, how to label all the lines.

Comment: What about trying yourself?  Using my example you should be able to change it accordingly.   If you run into a problem, you can still ask.

Comment: I have already done that. I was confused about the defined ctrl function, but I replaced that part with the point now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of my package for performing calculations with Feynman diagrams:

1.1 Define a set of Feynman diagrams

```
Clear[f, G, V]
f[0, 1][a_, b_, c_, d_] = 
 diag[g[a, i[1]], g[b, i[2]], g[i[1], c], g[i[2], d], v[i[1], i[2]]]
f[0, 2][a_, b_, c_, d_] = 
 diag[g[a, i[1]], g[b, i[2]], g[i[1], d], g[i[2], c], v[i[1], i[2]]]
```

1.2 Define a plotting function

```
pic[diag[x__]] := Module[{i, j, k},
    Graph[List[x] /. {g[i_, j_] -> DirectedEdge[j, i],
                        v[j_, k_] -> UndirectedEdge[j, k]},
                    VertexLabels -> "Name",
                    PlotTheme -> "Business",
                    ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> 10,
                    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 11],
                    GraphHighlight -> 
    Cases[List[x], v[i_, j_] -> UndirectedEdge[i, j]]]]
```

1.3 Depict 2 two-particle Green's functions to the first order in the Coulomb interaction

```
pic /@ {f[0, 1][a, b, c, d], f[0, 2][a, b, c, d]}
```

[image]

Let us do a bit more complicated stuff. We re-sum two-particle diagrams in the $T$-matrix (particle-particle channel) fashion

2.1 Define functions for contracting diagrams

```
vlist[diag[x__]] := Union[Flatten[Apply[List, List[x], 1]]]
contract[x__, vC_] := Module[{dlist, vtab, vE, vI, dj, rules, ka},
  dlist = List[x];
  (* replace contracted indices *)
  
  rules = Table[vC[[j]] -> i[0, j], {j, Length[vC]}];
  dlist = dlist /. rules;
  (* rename internals *)
  dlist = Table[dj = dlist[[j]];
    rules = Flatten[Cases[vlist[dj], i[ka_] -> {i[ka] -> i[j, ka]}]];
    dj /. rules, {j, Length[dlist]}];
  (*Combine diagrams together*)
  
  dlist = Apply[diag, Flatten[List @@@ dlist]];
  (* Rename internals*)
  vI = Cases[vlist[dlist], i[__]];
  dlist /. Rule @@@ Transpose[{vI, i /@ Ordering[vI]}]
  ]
```

2.2 Define $T$-matrix diagrams

```
f[1, 2][a_, b_, c_, d_] = 
  contract[f[0, 1][p, q, c, d], V[p, q], G[a, p], G[b, q], {p, q}];
f[2, 2][a_, b_, c_, d_] = 
  contract[f[1, 2][p, q, c, d], V[p, q], G[a, p], G[b, q], {p, q}];
f[3, 2][a_, b_, c_, d_] = 
  contract[f[2, 2][p, q, c, d], V[p, q], G[a, p], G[b, q], {p, q}];
```

2.3 and plot the result

```
f[3, 2][a, b, c, d] // pic
```

[image]